# Confusion With OOP in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP in Python but I'm confused about some parts.

```
class Song(object):

    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line

    def print_x(self):
        print x

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you,",
               "I don't want to get sued",
               "So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They'll rally around the family",
                    "With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()

x = Song(4)

x.print_x()
```

print_x() returns:

```
<__main__.Song object at 0x7f00459b4390>
```

instead of 4. So I try adding x to the parameters for `__init__` and `print_x`, and changing print x to print self.x in the `print_x` function plus adding `self.x` = x to init, but it returns this:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I honestly don't know what's gone awry here. But any help would be hugely beneficial to me finally understand OOP.

Comment: You're confusing the scopes of these variables. Local variables and instance variables are _completely_ different things.

Comment: You have to pass value of `x` at the time of creating instance. something like `happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you,",
               "I don't want to get sued",
               "So I'll stop right there"], 'x-value')`

Comment: What exactly should `print_x` return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is less an OOP issue and more of a scoping issue. Lets examine a very cut down version.

```
class Song(object):
    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def print_x(self):
        print x
```

From here we instantiate `x` (in the local scope):

```
>>> x = Song(4)
```

Now, before we do anything, lets examine `x`:

```
>>> print x.lyrics
4
```

The reason is that when you called `Song(4)` the value 4 is determined to be `lyrics` by its position.

And when we call `print_x`:

```
>>> x.print_x()
<__main__.Song object at 0x7f00459b4390> # Or some other memory address
```

The reason is that the only `x` that Python is aware of is the local  `x` we just made.

What happens when we start again and make `y`:

```
>>> y = Song(4)
>>> print y.print_x ()
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

No `x` exists to print and it throws an exception.

Comment: Despite the acceptance - I think there's a typo here.  You say that `print y.lyrics` will throw the `NameError`, but I think that will be fine.  I think the point you're trying to make is that `y.print_x()` will throw the `NameError`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying like

```
def __init__(self, lyrics, x):
    self.lyrics = lyrics
    self.x = x
...
def print_x(self):
    print self.x
```

By this way it will produce **TypeError: init() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)**

You can find the error from this.
When you creating `Song` instance like

```
happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you,",
           "I don't want to get sued",
           "So I'll stop right there"])
```

You have to pass the value of `x` to the `__init__()`.Thats why the error is showing.This can done by

```
 happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you,",
           "I don't want to get sued",
           "So I'll stop right there"],
            'x-value')
```

**OR**
Set default value for `x`

```
def __init__(self, lyrics, x="default value"):
    self.lyrics = lyrics
    self.x = x
```